# Suggestions on improving my code.

Tags: python

Hello I am a fairly novice programmer. And I have a simple code

```
name=raw_input("Hello I am Bob. What is your name?") 
print("It is very nice to meet you,", name) 
response=raw_input("what do you want to do today?") 
if response == "price match":
```

However on the fourth line I get `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing error` and I did look into it and I found that using the raw_input for inputted strings is much better than using the input function.I don't know why the error keeps popping up. Could I get some help and perhaps some suggestions as to how I can improve the code.

Comment: You probably need a statement after the `if ...:` line.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do *something* in the `if` statement. For example, print a price:

```
if response == "price match":
    print "Yes, we can do that for you".
```

But, you can't just leave a *block* (the stuff that is indented after a `:`) empty, or Python will give you an error.

---

In rare cases (and not in your case here), you may want to do absolutely nothing, but still have a block (e.g. if required to by an `except:`). In that case, you still have to put something in the block, but you can use the word `pass` which does nothing. (This is almost never used in an `if` block).

Comment: If you don't want to do anything, you can `pass` too:
    
`
    if response == "price match":
        pass
`

Answer (score 1):

I'm no Python expert.. But it looks like your problem is here:

```
response=raw_input("what do you want to do today?") if response == "price match":
```

You are defining an if statement, but if this value is true, how do you handle it?

I'm guessing you would need something like:

```
if response == "price match":
  print('Match')
 else:
    print('Did not match')
```

Hope this helps a little

Answer (score 0):

If you need a placeholder for just having valid syntax before putting in the body of your if/else/functions/etc, use pass.

http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/pass.html

As for your code, a valid if statement must always have a body. So put some code there or use pass.

Comment: This got me when I was first learning python as well. Pass is a really convenient.